# How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a query constructed in Java to search and fetch records,when constructing with the values **'** (**Single Quote**)(For Example:**New's**) then I'm not getting any results.

Here is the query where I am setting the value **New's**:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM AGX_THERAPEUTIC_AREA T WHERE  UPPER(T.THERAPEUTIC_NAME) LIKE ? ESCAPE \  OR  UPPER(T.THERAPEUTIC_AREA_DESC) LIKE ? ESCAPE \ 
    bind => [NEW'S%, NEW'S%]
```

Here is the method in which i am handling single quote:

```
public static String handleSingleQuote(String searchString) {
        if ((searchString == null) || searchString.trim().equals("")) {
            searchString = "";
        }

        searchString = searchString.trim();

        int length = searchString.length();
        StringBuffer searchBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            if (searchString.charAt(index) == '\'') {
                searchBuffer.append("''");
            } else {
                searchBuffer.append(searchString.charAt(index));
            }
        } // end of for loop

        searchString = searchBuffer.toString();

        return (searchString);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a query constructed in Java to search and fetch records,when constructing with the values ' (Single Quote)(For Example:New's) then I'm not getting any results.

Then you're constructing it incorrectly. It sounds like you're using string concatenation. [***Never do that***](http://bobby-tables.com/) *(see below)*. Instead, use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT FOO FROM BAR WHERE COLUMN LIKE ? ESCAPE \\"
);
ps.setString("this 'has' single quotes");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Your JDBC connector will ensure that the string is sent through correctly.

---

Re your comment saying you're using JPA: I don't know JPA, but [this page](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter) suggests it would look something like:

```
TypedQuery<Thingy> query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT FOO FROM BAR WHERE COLUMN LIKE :search ESCAPE \\",
    Thingy.class
);
return query.setParameter("search", "this 'has' quotes").getSingleResult();
```

---

Re "**never do that**":

[image]

Comment: Yes,I am constructing query using string concatenation and i am using JPA.Can you modify that query which one i posted so that i can understand where is wrong.The query i posted that is from server console after execution.

Comment: @Mihir: Apologies, don't know JPA. I found a page and added a link to it and a query above, but as I don't know JPA, I can't guarantee it...

Answer (score 2):

You can escape it by making it two single quotes.

```
select 'Hello y''all!' from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape it using quotes

```
SELECT 'New''s' AS text FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String handleSingleQuote(String searchString) {
        if ((searchString == null) || searchString.trim().equals("")) {
            searchString = "";
        }

        searchString = searchString.trim();

        int length = searchString.length();
        StringBuffer searchBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            if (searchString.charAt(index) == '\'') {
                searchBuffer.append("\'");
            } else {
                searchBuffer.append(searchString.charAt(index));
            }
        } // end of for loop

        searchString = searchBuffer.toString();

        return (searchString);
    }
```